# Converting from UTC to Central Time ('America/Chicago') using moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I believe this instruction should convert correctly from UTC to CST but seems like is an hour off

```
moment.utc('07-18-2013 16:10:11', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm').tz('America/Chicago').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
```

It returs `2013-07-18 11:10` when it should return `2013-07-18 10:10`

Am I missing something?

Edit: If I print the abbreviated Time Zone I get `CDT` instead of `CST`. How can I specify CST?

Comment: Did you import `moment-timezone` with datas?

Comment: Probably not, I'm new to moment, could you redirect me into the right direction?

Comment: You can read how to use moment in the broswer in the [docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/browser/), basically you need to import [`moment-timezone-with-data.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js) after `moment.js`.

Comment: I have this in my package.json file:
  `"moment": "^2.17.1",`
  `"moment-timezone": "^0.5.11",`

Is there a npm package to install `moment-timezone-with-data`?

Comment: Your code is fine and your result is correct, `2013-07-18 11:10` UTC **is** `2013-07-18 11:10` in Chicago as shown [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20130718T161000&p1=1440&p2=64). You get `CDT` (Central Daylight Time) because of daylight saving.

Comment: Is there a way to use `CST` directly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is correct, and as VincenzoC pointed out in comments, DST is in effect at that time, which is why you get the result you did.

You're using `America/Chicago`, which means literally - the time in Chicago.  It is representative of the entire Central time zone in the United States.  There are no places in the US that use Central time without daylight saving time, so asking for that would be nonsensical/invalid.

If you really *didn't* mean US Central time, your other options would be:

- Choose the correct time zone.

  ```
  .tz('America/Regina')        // Saskatchewan, Canada     (UTC-6 all year)
  .tz('America/Tegucigalpa')   // Honduras, South America  (UTC-6 all year)
  ```
- Use a fixed offset instead of a time zone.  (You won't need the moment-timezone add-on for this.)

  ```
  .utcOffset('-06:00')
  ```

Comment: Perfect! Now I understand. Thanks :)