# Convert CST/CDT to UTC Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, dst

I have time in string format, which is local time in CDT or CST (Depending upon if daylight saving is going on or not).
Ex-

```
2021-08-19 15:55:40
```

So its just string data, there is no indication of tz, I want to convert this local time to UTC.
What can be the best way to do that?
Is there an already existing npm package that can identify and convert automatically?

Code that I'm currently trying to use:
As a first step I am trying to convert DateTime to ISO, which can be converted to UTC easily

```
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
var overrideZone = DateTime.fromSQL("2021-05-15 23:10:23", { zone: "America/Mexico_City" });

console.log(overrideZone.toISO()) //=> '2021-05-16T11:10:23.000-05:00'
```

It's giving me date as 16thMay, But Clearly I mean 15th May 23:10 (11:10 PM) not 16th.

I don't know whats wrong in my code

Comment: did you try `momentjs`? [MomentJs](https://momentjs.com)

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41728401/7865759) answer

Comment: I am trying to use Luxon (successor of moment), But getting unexpected results,

For First step I'm trying to convert datetime to ISO string(with correct tz), So that I can get UTS easily: 

`const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
var overrideZone = DateTime.fromSQL("2021-05-15 23:10:23", { zone: "America/Mexico_City" });
console.log(overrideZone.toISO()) //=> '2021-05-16T11:10:23.000-05:00'`

Here I am getting date as 16th but my date is 15th, I don't know whats wrong

Comment: can you add your code to question?

Comment: @AminTaghikhani added

Comment: it's because of timezone, `America/Mexico_City` is `05:00` hours behind of `UTC`

Comment: @AminTaghikhani But I am giving a date that is already in `American/Mexico` time zone, This function should not add 12 hrs to it, Also facing same issue while using @terry's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the [DateTime.fromFormat()](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromformat) function to parse the date string, using a format of 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'.

You can convert the `DateTime` timezone to UTC using the [setZone()](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimesetzone) function. We'd set the zone to 'UTC' to convert to UTC time.

**NB:** The working fix here is to upgrade from Node 10.24 to at least Node 12.x

```js
let { DateTime } = luxon;

const dateStr = '2021-05-15 23:10:23';
const zone = 'America/Mexico_City';

const dt = DateTime.fromFormat(dateStr, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', { zone });
const utcTime = dt.setZone('UTC');

console.log('Local time (Central):', dt.toISO());
console.log('UTC time:', utcTime.toISO());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.0.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-bI2nHaBnCCpELzO7o0RB58ULEQuWW9HRXP/qyxg/u6WakLJb6wz0nVR9dy0bdKKGo0qOBa3s8v9FGv54Mbp3aA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Running the same code using Node.js 14.15.5 and luxon 2.0.2 on Windows 10.0.19043.0 gives the result:

```
Local time (Central): 2021-05-15T23:10:23.000-05:00
UTC time: 2021-05-16T04:10:23.000Z
```

So it may be due to a difference in environment. Have you tried using a later version of Node.js?

Using the `node:10.24` Docker image I get the following output

```
Local time (Central): 2021-05-16T11:10:23.000-05:00
UTC time: 2021-05-16T16:10:23.000Z
```

So it looks to me like a Node.js version issue. I would suggest trying a later Node.js release. I've tried node v12.16.1 and I get the correct output. So I would suggest trying at least node v12 to resolve your issue.

Comment: it's working fine for me in the browser, But when running on my system(node) its giving result with adding 12 hrs to it,

`Local time (Central): 2021-05-16T11:10:23.000-05:00
UTC time: 2021-05-16T16:10:23.000Z` This is the output I received running on my system. Notice date has been changed to 16th and time 11 morning, in local time, which should not be done, but it's happening

Comment: That's very strange for sure.  What version of Node.js and Luxon are you using? I'll try to see if I can get the same result.

Comment: node- v10.24.1, luxon- 2.0.2, Same issue I am also facing when the code is running in gcp cloud function

Comment: Looks to me (check my updated answer) like the Node.js version is the problem. Node v12 and up give the correct result.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me out, Updating node version fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Excellent, that's a great outcome!